# Proving that a positive partial transpose (PPT) state is non-distillable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, information

I am attempting to prove the following statement: A  positive partial transpose (PPT) state cannot be distilled.

I would like to do so using the following facts:

- Let $\rho$ represent a bipartite quantum state. We may write $\rho$ via matrix elements in a product basis, $\rho_{m\mu, n\nu} = \langle m\mu \;|\rho \;| n\nu \rangle$. We define the partial transposition map, $T_B$, as follows: $T_B(\rho)_{m\mu, n\nu} = \rho^{T_B}_{m\mu,n\nu} = \rho_{m\nu,n\mu} = \langle m\nu\;|\rho\;|n\mu\rangle$. A state is said to have a positive partial transpose (PPT) if and only if all eigenvalues of its partial transpose are non-negative or, equivalently, if and only if $\rho^{T_B}\geq 0$
- Suppose a bipartite quantum state, $\rho$, is separable. Then, $\rho$ must be PPT, i.e. $\rho^{T_B}\geq 0$
- A state $\rho$ is distillable if and only if for some two-dimensional projectors P, Q and for some number n, the state $(P\bigotimes Q̺)\rho^{\bigotimes n} (P\bigotimes Q)$ is entangled.

My rough attempt:

Let $\rho$ denote a PPT bipartite state. Therefore, $\rho^{T_B}\geq 0$. By the second fact
listed above, if a state is NPT it cannot be separable therefore it is entangled. Therefore $\rho$ is distillable only if $\sigma = (P\bigotimes Q̺)\rho^{\bigotimes n} (P\bigotimes Q)$ is NPT (negative partial transpose).

Let us consider the partial transpose of $\sigma$: $(P\bigotimes Q̺)[\rho^{T_B}]^{\bigotimes n} (P\bigotimes Q)$. Side note: how would I prove more formally that this is the partial transpose of $\sigma$?

It's somewhat clear to me that the partial transpose of $\sigma$ must be positive, since $\rho$ is PPT. This is logical, and I believe it would complete the proof. However, I have two queries:

1. How to formalize the fact that the partial transpose of $\sigma$ is $(P\bigotimes Q̺)[\rho^{T_B}]^{\bigotimes n} (P\bigotimes Q)$, or is this immediately clear?
2. How to rigorously state that $\rho^{T_B}\geq 0\rightarrow (P\bigotimes Q̺)[\rho^{T_B}]^{\bigotimes n} (P\bigotimes Q) \geq 0$.

Perhaps the key to the second issue lies in the fact that $P,Q$ are co - positive maps, but is this necessarily true?

Any suggestions or corrections would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: related on qc.SE: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8577/55

Answer (score 1):

(1) is not true -- you have to transpose Q as well.

(2) That should be obvious, since (a) $X\ge0\ \Rightarrow X^{\otimes n}\ge 0$, and (b) $Y\ge0\ \Rightarrow\ AYA^\dagger\ge0$.

Comment: On a more general note, the key point is that LOCC (and more generally separable superoperators) leave PPT states PPT, and thus cannot yield an output which approaches copies of the maximally entangled state.